# Width of fake responsive background based on height of device?

Tags: html, css

I have a image gallery that uses as main image a size of 1024x768px.
The gallery shows ok except one case. If the main image (#original-picture) will not load, the gallery will shows only the vertical thumbnails (will collapse).

Is it possible to make a fake white background that behaves exactly the same as #original-picture (to prevent collapse of the gallery)? So have 100% height in landscape mode and width with same aspect as it is in 1024x768px?

This is the demo i have made https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/t1akegcd/13/ so you can resize the area and see how it behaves and also what happens if you hide main image.

```
<div class="modal-background show-modal">
  <div class="modal1">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport ">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <div id="image-background"></div>
        <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" id="original-picture" alt="" width="" height="">
        <div class="enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs">
          <ul class="clearfix thumbs_nav">
            <li id="picture1modal" class="1 active vis on" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture2modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture3modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture4modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture5modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture6modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture7modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.modal-background {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  z-index: 9998;
}

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 0 linear 0, opacity .25s 0, transform .25s;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal1 {
  transition: visibility 0 linear .25s, opacity .25s 0, transform .25s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #dedede;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 66px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li span {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  float: left;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .modal1 {
    width: auto;
    height: 768px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
    order: 2;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
    order: 1;
    width: 65px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 66px;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .modal1 {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    top: 8%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 8%);
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
    order: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. The idea is to have an element with height set to zero, and then set the top or bottom padding to a percent. This percent will be a percent of the element's width. It's counterintuitive at first, but it is a rather widely used trick. That container element will maintain the aspect ratio. Then you can absolutely position a child element that takes up the space within the container.

```css
.aspect-ratio-4x3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 75%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="aspect-ratio-4x3">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to apply what you said to the demo and is not working because i use a image of 1024x768px, responsive based on height: 100% in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, in case others needs it https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/t1akegcd/70/

I made a background image of 1024x768px via http://png-pixel.com and add it after the main image. In addition, i added position: absolute to #original-picture so that both images have same position and now it works. If i disable the real image, the white one will show, maintaining the gallery aspect.

```
<div class="modal-background show-modal">
  <div class="modal1">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport ">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" id="original-picture" alt="" width="" height="">

        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <div class="enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs">
          <ul class="clearfix thumbs_nav">
            <li id="picture1modal" class="1 active vis on" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture2modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture3modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture4modal" class="1 vis" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture5modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture6modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
            <li id="picture7modal" class="2" onclick="javascript:;"><span><a href="javascript:;"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7800000/the-male-lion-all-about-lions-7875244-1024-768.jpg" alt="thumb"></a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#image-background {
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
}
.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 0 linear 0, opacity .25s 0, transform .25s;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal1 {
  transition: visibility 0 linear .25s, opacity .25s 0, transform .25s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  justify-content: center;
}
.close-button {

    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #dedede;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    right: -40px;

}

#image-background {
  display: inline-block;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img#original-picture {
  position: absolute;
}
.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li span {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  float: left;
}


@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .modal1 {
    width: auto;
    height: 768px;
    /*left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  }
  .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport {
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
    order: 2;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
    order: 1;
    width: 65px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 66px;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .modal1 {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    top: 8%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 8%);
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_viewport img {
    order: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs {
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs ul {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .enlarge_picture_modal_holder_thumbs li {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```